# Assign different IIS App pool to a web service using WIX

Tags: iis, wix

I created a new IIS Application pool named "myAppPool" and I'm trying to assign my wcf web service, "myWebService" to this newly created app pool. is it possible for me to do it using wix?

I've done some research and found this link -> http://blog.bartdemeyer.be/2013/10/create-an-installer-for-website-with-wix-part-3/ which is helpful but, he installed a website first and assigned the app pool to the new web site. But I need to assign the web service to a different app pool without creating a new website.

Has anyone done this before? Is this possible or applicable using WIX?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the service as a web application under an existing site, you should be able to do something like this:

```
<Component Id="MySite.MyWebService" Directory="TARGETDIR" Guid="[GUID]">
  <CreateFolder />
  <iis:WebVirtualDir Id="VirtualDir.Service.MyWebService" Alias="MyWebService" Directory="TARGETDIR" WebSite="MySite">
    <iis:WebApplication Id="Application.Service.MyWebService" Name="MyWebService" WebAppPool="MyAppPool" />
  </iis:WebVirtualDir>
</Component>
```

The virtual directory should be where your service "lives".